WPF - how to create completely custom element
I am trying to create something like this: https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/ in a WPF app, but I am not really sure how to approach it. I think I need to create something like a custom element with specific behavior, but I am not really sure if it is even possible to do.
I thought of using something like Canvas and create my own renderer of the graph but the main issue I had to resolve was that this approach was too slow because when I needed to render 30+ frames per second, It just couldn't handle it. And the second issue was that I wasn't able to implement the possibility to interact with the graph.

You may want to start reading here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

"I wasn't able to implement the possibility to interact with the graph." - When you use the Canvas and simply add objects derived from Shape, or Path for more complex shapes, you get the user interaction interface for free (e.g. hit testing). "this approach was too slow because when I needed to render 30+ frames per second" - Performance is usually good with the Canvas for simple layouts. It would be interesting to see how you handled the Canvas that yields an unsatisfying performance. Are you animating the graph or why are you concerned with frames per second?

You could create a new WPF object extending FrameworkElement and then override the drawing method, this should be significantly faster.
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(null, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, Height));
}

You could look over here for a complete example.
To interact with the control you should override the mouse events and check whenever the click is in an object drawn.
If this is too slow you may want to look to something else like using opengl (opentk) or skiasharp.
Another approach could be to render all in a WriteableBitmap and then just draw it.
See also this question for more solutions.
